# Using Apache HttpComponents for http requests with NTLM authentication

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, apache-httpclient-4.x

Quick background.

CFHTTP doesn't support Windows NTLM/Authenticate authentication, only basic authentication. I need to make http requests that will have to authenticate against NTLM, so I've ended up rolling my own version of CFHTTP.

I found [Terry Ryan's article](http://www.terrenceryan.com/blog/post.cfm/digest-authentication-in-coldfusion) that uses the apache httpclient version 3.1 to perform digest authentication and have built upon that using version 4.1.2 instead which includes NTLM functionality.

I have a function that will perform a get request and then other functions to handle returning a structure that looks like the cfhttp result set. The changes I made are based on the [authentication tutorial example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#d4e1031).

```
public any function httpRequest(url,username,password,domain) {
    var httpClient = createObject("java","org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient");
    var authScope = createObject("java","org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope");
    var httpCredentials = createObject("java","org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials");
    var httpGet = createObject("java","org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet");
    var jURL = createObject("java", "java.net.URL").init(arguments.url);
    var host = jURL.getHost();
    var path = jURL.getPath();
    var httpHostTarget = createObject("java","org.apache.http.HttpHost").init(host,80,"http");
    var localContext = createObject("java","org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext");
    var httpContent = {};
    var response = '';

    if (len(arguments.username) and len(arguments.password) gt 0){
        httpCredentials.init(arguments.Username, arguments.password, cgi.remote_host,arguments.domain);
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope.ANY, httpCredentials);
    }

    if (!Len(path)) path = "/";
    httpGet.init(path);

    response = httpClient.execute(httpHostTarget, httpget, localContext);

    httpContent = convertHttpClientResponseToCFHTTPFormat(response);

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    return httpContent;
}
```

This was working fine until I altered the function to perform the authentication.

Unfortunately I'm now getting :

> The execute method was not found.
>
> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the execute method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 2 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.

As far as I can tell there is only one matching execute() function in HttpClient for the object classes passed to it, so I'm a little confused. JavaCast doesn't allow you to cast to complex objects or super types, so that didn't work.

Can anyone suggest how I can get this to work? How can I reduce the ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error, it's getting confused between two execute methods that have the same number of parameters.  Although I don't know why it is...

Anyway, I found a way around the error.  It involves pulling the method you're after out of the class and invoking it directly.  If ColdFusion was happier with casting Java objects life might be easier.

```
//response = httpClient.execute(httpHostTarget, httpget, localContext);

classes = [httpHostTarget.getClass(), CreateObject('java', 'org.apache.http.HttpRequest').getClass(), CreateObject('java', 'org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext').getClass()];
method = httpClient.getClass().getMethod('execute', classes);
params = [httpHostTarget, httpget, localContext];
response = method.invoke(httpClient, params);
```

There may be another way of doing this (casting instead) but it's all I've got ;)

Comment: is quite correct - this does work to get the method to execute.  However, and this is a problem that I ran into with other solutions I came up with, the code still doesn't actually authenticate against IIS and the windows integrated login.  I'm going to mark this question as answered, because it is, but unfortunately, the bigger picture is still broken using these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, could you be loading the wrong version of the .jars ? You don't seem to be using JavaLoader like Ryan did...

Comment: I kinda bypassed the whole JavaLoader malarkey by dropping the jars from http core and client into the jre/lib/ext folder on the server. looking at the httpclient object execute methods I can the one I want to call and my object types for httpHostTarget, httpget and localContext match the ones expected for that method and no others, but still it throws this error.

Comment: @Stephen - The error says two (*2*) methods found. I do not see two (2) methods that match that signature. Unless I am overlooking an inherited class .. ?

Comment: @Leigh Yep. That is exactly the problem I'm having.  I can only see one method that matches. There are, however, are 2 execute methods with 3 params. These methods have different classes for the params.

Comment: @Stephen - Not to restate the obvious ;).. but something seems fishy with how CF is detecting the signatures. Do you know which CF version Terry was using? Because I tried both his and your approach (ie `jre/lib/ext`) with CF9 and neither worked. I could not even invoke that method with java reflection - which is odd.

Comment: 2009 would suggest ColdFusion 8 - I'm on CF 9.0.1. A colleague and I discovered today that if you drop the local context the function executes, but we can't get the credentials to be passed through.

Comment: We also tried using msxml2.xmlhttp, which worked great under CF8 32bit, but as soon as we ran it under CF9 x64 it all fell apart. msxml2.xmlhttp is 32bit & the x64 version doesn't load a x64 COM object for reason. Maddening given that 3 lines of code does exactly what I need.

Comment: @Stephen - Re: *if you drop the local context* yeah, I noticed that too. Re: *suggests ColdFusion 8* Hm... maybe it is a CF9 specific problem. That gives me a few ideas. Let me give them a whirl and see if they pan out.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not have any more luck w/.net classes than you did w/java.

Comment: @StephenMoretti - I think I got ntlm it working using .net classes. It was painful though. For some reason CF did not create all the referenced classes at first(?). So I ended up doing it manually with `jnbproxy`. But once that was done it seemed to work fine under CF9/x64. Let me know if you want to go that route.

Comment: @Leigh I've ended up with a solution that uses an open source java library called Jacob to call msxml2.xmlhttp under the ColdFusion. Its a little convoluted, but basically Jacob allows you to call COM objects (regardless of whether they are 32 or 64 bit) from Java.  Currently we have a custom class to make the http request, but a colleague of mine is now looking at building a wrapper for Jacob so that we can call any COM object from ColdFusion, bypassing the 32/64 bit restriction of createobject("com","blah") as we have a few use cases for this.

Comment: @Stephen - I was wondering if jni might be a possibility. That sounds like a great idea. Hopefully you will blog about it when you are finished :) I would love to see the finished product (if you can share it).